# How Can I Extract an IPA from an iPhone for an App Downloaded from the App Store so that I can see the assets in the IPA?

Tags: ios, iphone

One of my favorite apps was removed from the app store, i guess because it hadn't been updated in too long. I have it on an old device (approx iOS 7.1.2) but did not download it onto my new phones.

How do I get the IPA so that I can look at the app bundle and see the assets in the app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, one of the possible solution to get into the assets of any app is using the iTunes and a little magic.

In your case you can easy synchronize your device with iTunes to get all apps from your devices copied into iTunes Media Folder:

[image]

And after that you can just unarchive an ipa file and navigate to `Payload/AnAppName.app` and there should be all assets of the application.

Sample with using your terminal:

```
$  cd ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/
$  tar -zxf Apple\ Store\ 401000.ipa
$  cd Payload/Apple\ Store.app/
```

And the result will be:

[image]

PS: instead of using bash for unarchiving, you can just change the extention of ipa-file from `.ipa` to `.zip` and after that double click on it.

Comment: iTunes v12.7 (released Sept 2017) removes the App Store, and this will no longer work. You can download older versions of iTunes directly from Apple, all versions are linked to here: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/ITunes 

```Edit: I was unable to install an older version of iTunes. The iTunes installer won't install over a newer version, and MacOS won't let you Trash it, says 'iTunes can't be modified or deleted, as is required by macOS'.```