# Get provisioning profile from iPhone local files

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile

We signed an Enterprize application with a provisioning profile.
And launched the application on an iPhone device.

My question is:

How can I get the provisioning profile from that iPhone?
Can I get to the files using USB?
Or there is a way to programmatically get the profile file data?

Comment: Not sure... but you can try iphone Configuration utility

Comment: Programmatically, the file should exist inside your application's main bundle as "embedded.mobileprovision".

Comment: How to reach this bundle?

Comment: Do you no longer have access to the Apple developer account?  You can simply re-download it from the site.  The provisioning profile isn't worth anything without the certificate / private key - do you have those for the profile?

Comment: Also, do you have access to the .ipa file for the app? If so, you can extract it from that.

Comment: So how can I extract the profile from a .ipa? I do have access to Apple site but the required provision has changed so many times. I'm trying to achieve the profile that signed a specific app for specific customer

Comment: To the downvoter, feel free to downvote if you feel like it but leave a comment to why you downvoted and give me feedback!

Comment: To get it from the ipa, you can change the .ipa extension to .zip, and extract the files.  Inside, there is an embedded.mobileprovision that is the provisioning profile that was packaged with the app when it was built.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extract the IPA from iTunes using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41165422/3708242). Or, if you already have the original ipa that was installed to the device, even better.

Once you have the .ipa, you can change the .ipa extension to .zip and extract the contents. On a Mac, in Finder, you should get a folder called "Payload". Inside that folder will be a .app.  Right click on the .app and choose "Show package contents".  Inside the .app is a file called `embedded.mobileprovision`. That is the provisioning profile that was packaged with the app when it was build, and subsequently installed on the iOS device when it was installed from the .plist/.ipa.